# How can I deploy my site from a different computer when using a gh-pages working tree?

Tags: github, version-control, github-pages

I have a GitHub pages site which I started working on from another computer. I cloned the repo from GitHub but it didn't clone the gh-pages folder. I have my main "site" folder and within it a "gh-pages" folder where I deploy my site from. The gh-pages folder is on its own working tree. Since this working tree does not exist on the computer I am working on now, how can I compile the site on the new computer and push it to my gh-pages branch? Thanks!

Comment: It would be useful if you tell us the kind of project it is or add some code to the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set everything up correctly it should just be you run the predeploy script (something like `npm run build`) in your terminal/cli.